# Angular cli - output of component styles

Tags: angular

I'm using the angular cli with styles added to each component using the styleUrls link

When testing locally this seems to output `<style>` tags to the head of the document

Does Angular output a `<style>` tag for each component with style added with styleUrls

If it does is this locally or will this be the case in production.

Comment: ng build --prod and check what is built

Comment: What does ng build --prod do

Comment: Builds for production ??

Answer (score 0):

It does this in production as well, but only once for each *type* of component. E.g. if you have 100 components in an `*ngFor`, it will only insert the styles for them all once. This is how they scope styles to only apply to the elements within that component's template.